# Importing value of a variable from one file to another without executing the function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I have a script `test.py` which contains two functions `sum()` summing up two values and `meth()` calling `sum()` and storing result in a variable `c`. My intention is to run `meth()` and get the value stored in variable `c` first and then want to use this value in another script `demo.py` without executing `sum()` again. is it possible?

test.py

```
def sum(a,b):
    print("inside sum function")
    return a+b
    
def meth():
    c = sum(7,5)
    return c
```

The solution I tried:

I am getting value of variable `c` by calling meth() in `demo.py` But it is executing `sum()` function also.

demo.py

```
import test.py as tes
val = tes.meth()
```

output:

```
=> Inside sum function
=> 12
```

I want to run `test.py` first and store the value in variable `c` and use it in `demo.py` without executing `sum()` function again.

Comment: But... Didn't it work? `test.py` was executed correctly, and the final result `12` is now stored in val.

Comment: It worked but meth() is again getting executed which is calling sum() also. I want to use only variable value in demo.py without calling any of the functions

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you, but there's no way to call meth() without calling sum() as well, since meth() itself calls sum(). But after calling `tes.meth()` val will store 12 without needing to call meth() ever again

Comment: It's very hard to answer your question because your example makes no sense; you create two functions that are no more than primitives. You should elaborate on your use of this and why you need this particular behavior. This is a XY problem, we can't help you because we don't know what you **really** want to do.

Comment: In *test.py*: `c = meth()`. In *demo.py*: `from test import c`.

Comment: They want to run `sum()` once and then fetch that result again later, in a different process, without running `sum()` again.

Answer (score 1):

Every time that you call `meth()`, it will invoke `sum()`. When that process exits, the memory is freed and the results of the sum are lost until you run the function again.

If you want to store that result somewhere then you could write it to a file, e.g. as text or some binary format or even using pickle, and then load it later in some other process. You'd have to modify `meth()` to store the result of `sum()`, and then have it check for that file the next time that it's invoked. This is basically caching, and there are all kinds of modules that will let you do advanced caching if you want to go beyond storing the sum of 2 numbers in a file.

Comment: ekhumoro comment has the solution, no need to use a temp file write and multiple time read (very inefficient), we are not talking persistent storage

Comment: it doesn't work. already tried. it will call sum function again

Comment: @rioV8 that comment does not actually answer the question being posed; when you import a module all of the code in that module gets processed, so simply setting a variable to the output of `meth()` will cause `sum()` to be reinvoked, which is the specific thing that the OP wants to avoid. So the the result has to be stored somewhere after it's calculated the first time in order to avoid calculating it a second time. A file is suitable for this

Comment: there is a difference between define a function and call a function. By calling `meth()` once, `sum()` gets called once

Comment: @Michael It's not clear from the question why they ***need*** to run the two scripts separately. As pointed out previously, the question currently looks like an XY problem. It may be that the OP could side-step the issue by simply re-structuring their code (hence my suggested solution).

Comment: @ekhumoro the last line of their post makes it pretty clear that they want to calculate something in one process, and use the results in a later process. The OP is clear about wanting to run 2 separate processes, so this answers that question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a file called `test.py` because `test` is a buildin module.

In `mytest.py` call `sum()` and store it in a hidden module variable. Use this variable when you call `meth()`

`mytest.py`

```
def sum(a,b):
    print("inside sum function")
    return a+b

_singleCallOfSumInMeth = sum(7,5)

def meth():
    return _singleCallOfSumInMeth
```

`demo.py`

```
import mytest
print('After import, before calling meth()')
val = mytest.meth()
val = mytest.meth()
val = mytest.meth()
val = mytest.meth()
print(f'val={val}')
```

**Output**

```
inside sum function
After import, before calling meth()
```

`inside sum function` is printed because of the `import mytest`. And it is printed only once and we call `meth()` multiple times. So `sum()` is only called once while calling `meth()`

Comment: I tried using _singleCallOfSumInMeth or calling meth()  in demo.py but it is calling sum() again

Comment: @AbhinandanMehandiratta How do you expect to get a value from `sum()` without calling it? See my update